# SSRS Plotting 0 for entries filtered by where clause

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've got a query pulling number of error codes per server per minute and need to graph that over time (separate graphs grouped by code & server). The problem I'm having is that for any given error code there are minutes that may not contain that code. So I end up with a table like this:

```
Minute Server   ErrCount  ErrCode
14:54   SRVRNAME    154 1163 
14:53   SRVRNAME    319 1163 
14:53   SRVRNAME    1   4999
14:53   SRVRNAME    1   312007 
14:52   SRVRNAME    167 1163    
14:51   SRVRNAME    71  1163 
14:50   SRVRNAME    2   1163 
14:49   SRVRNAME    31  1163    
14:48   SRVRNAME    6   1163 
14:47   NULL        0   NULL 
14:46   NULL        0   NULL 
14:45   SRVRNAME    11  1163 
14:44   SRVRNAME    26  1163    
14:43   SRVRNAME    94  1163 
14:42   SRVRNAME    305 1163 
14:42   SRVRNAME    1   4999
```

If I filter on error code 4999 I only get the entries for 14:42 and 14:53, but I want to graph all the other times as an error count of 0. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to structure your data so that it provides those rows.  SSRS reports on the data it is given.  If your data provides rows with 0s then SSRS will report them.  Here's a link to a similar question I answered on how to structure your data.  Hope this helps.

[SSRS RB3 X-Axis last 30 minutes plus graphing 0 for gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029946/ssrs-rb3-x-axis-last-30-minutes-plus-graphing-0-for-gaps/21031219#21031219)